# How to get javascript object attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get object attribute which is also an object.

```
$scope.posts = Post.find();
console.log($scope.posts);
```

In console this returns me:

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
    >0: Resource   //this is an object that I need
    >1: Resource
    >2: Resource
    >$promise: Promise
    $resolved: false
    >__proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I get Resources 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: $scope.posts[0] ?? I think you could do more research, this is bacis question and i am sure you could find the solution by your self...

Comment: create jsfiddle/jsbin for same.

Comment: I did research. I eve try to get item by heir keys. It only return $promise and $resolved. Not Resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Post.find()` is returning a promise, You should use assign the returned data in the resolved callback of `then()`

Its returning you an array, whose elements can be accessed using index.

```
Post.find().then(function(data){
    $scope.posts = data;
    console.log($scope.posts[0]); //Access the first element of array
})
```

Comment: $scope.posts is not an array. It's an object, and it does not working $scope.posts[0]  it is undefined. I was trying to do that first.

Comment: @neeev: note the usage of `then` in this answer. It is very important.

Comment: then is not working, but I know how to get callback function. data returned me right thing. Thanks!